# How do you make a vector of class objects?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm a bit confused as to how vectors work. What I'm trying to do is create a vector of 5 `TaxBill` objects. Then, what I want to do is read from an input file that has the names and different tax rates for 5 states. I want to store the name of the state in the object and the tax rates of the state in an array in `int main()`.

Here's the input file called "Tax Rates.dat". The numbers are the sales, property and income tax rate, respectively, for each state.

```
TEXAS      .0825 .02 -.03
MARYLAND   .065 .04 .05
OHIO       .03 .025 .03
CALIFORNIA .095 .055 .045
MAINE      .02 .015 .02
```

Here's my class interface called "Tax Bill.h".

```
using namespace std;

class TaxBill
{
public:
      void setValue(string, int);
      void dataValid(double&, double&, double&);

private:
      string Name;
      int index;
      double taxBill;
}
```

Here's my class implementation called "Tax Bill.cpp".

```
#include "Tax Bill.h"

void TaxBill::setValue(string name, int x)
{}


void TaxBill::dataValid(double& a, double& b, double& c)
{
      if(a < 0)
            a = 0;
      if(b < 0)
            b = 0;
      if(c < 0)
            c = 0;

      return;
}
```

Here's my main source code so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "Tax Bill.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
      const int SALARY = 100000,
            HOUSE = 246000,
            PURCHASE = 36000;
      ifstream fin;
      fin.open("Tax Rates.dat");
      vector <TaxBill> someVector (5);
      double sales,
            property,
            income;
      double taxRates[5][3];
      string name;

      if(!fin)
            return 0;
      else
      {
            for(int i = 0; fin >> name >> sales >> property >> income; i++)
            {
                  dataValid(sales, property, income);
                  taxRates[i][0] = sales;
                  taxRates[i][1] = property;
                  taxRates[i][2] = income;
            }
      }
```

The for loop is where I want to store the name of the state read from the input file and `i` into the string `Name` and `index` of the class object. The reason for the index is because later in the program I want to sort the objects in the vector alphabetically but not the array where the corresponding tax rates are stored.

I also don't want to use the function `push_back()`.

I guess my question is, how do I make an vector of 5 class objects and access them?

Please keep in mind that my program is hardly complete and it's this one hurdle that's holding me back.

Comment: This `taxRates[i,0]` is not going to do what I think you think it does.

Comment: just vector of other classes, assign objects to it like `someVector[0]=....;`

Comment: @mathematician1975  What's wrong with it?

Comment: its the comma operator. To index use `[i][n]`.

Comment: `double taxRates[5,3]; taxRates[i,0] = sales;` Where did you learn this?

Comment: @Thomas Oh ok. I completely forgot about that. I need more sleep. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here example of using vector from your code. Here you declare

```
vector <TaxBill> someVector (5);
```

So now, you have someVector[0] - [4] (5 in total). To use it, actually you just have to assign it like an normal array.

```
someVector[0].{insert property here}
```

But wait, in your class, there is no clear way to set the string Name and Index. So i think you forget to place it here, hence i make my own in the class.

```
class TaxBill
{
public:
      void setValue(string Name, int Index){
         name = Name; index = Index;
      }
      void dataValid(double&, double&, double&);

private:
      string name;
      int index;
      double taxBill;
}
```

Now to use the vector, i just used the property this way

```
someVector[0].setValue("someName",1);
```

Tada, you get it to works. Btw, i dont know why you declare a procedure in the class, but you want to used it multiple times in main program. I mean this one

```
dataValid(sales, property, income);
```

to used it, i suggest you make a procedure in main program rather than in class and anyway that line should produce an error anyway. :)

Comment: If this help you, please upvote or chose as an answer rather than say thanks in comment so it will help others too.

Comment: My upvote doesn't count because I'm brand new to the site but I chose it as an answer.